# Getting application branding information

Tags: eclipse-rcp

When an Eclipse RCP IApplication starts up, it gets passed an IApplicationContext object containing a lot of branding and configuration info. I'd like to get any of that same information -- i.e., the result of calling getBrandingApplication() or getBrandingName() -- from an arbitrary other plugin, not the application plugin, without the cooperation of the application plugin. In other words, is there any method I can call at runtime to get the id or location of the currently running IApplication?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`IApplicationContext` is defined as an OSGi service so you can access it from any plugin using a `ServiceTracker` or other method of access services. Something like:

```
ServiceTracker appContext = new ServiceTracker(bundle, IApplicationContext.class, null);
appContext.open();

IApplicationContext context = appContext.getService();
```

You can also access some of the information using the `getProperty` method of `IProduct` which you get from `Platform.getProduct()`.

In an Eclipse 4 'e4' application `IApplicationContext` is in the Eclipse context and can be injected.